# mixing Ajax with Javascript

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

I foundout that I cant mix php with javascript so I ttried AJAX. in the code below I want the ajax function to get a value from getcount.php page and return it to the caller function. the code below doesnt work. where is the mistake?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function getcount(day)
{
var xmlhttp;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }

xmlhttp.open("GET","getcount.php?"+day,true);
xmlhttp.send();

xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    return xmlhttp.responseText;   
    }
}
 </script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
var previousPoint;

var d1 = [];
 for (var i = 0; i <= 10; i += 1)
         d1.push([i, getcount(i)]);
  .
  .
  .
```

Comment: Your title is a bit weird: AJAX is Javascript

Comment: You're missing a closing } at the end of the getcount function. Try to keep a consistent code indentation, then that kind of thing is obvious quickly :)

Answer (score 3):

The ajax callback will be asynchronous so, getcount() will return undefined and when the callback returns it is not assigned to anything

```
function getcount(day, arr) {
var xmlhttp;
...
xmlhttp.send();

xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
    arr.push([day, xmlhttp.responseText]);   
    }
}
$(function () {
var previousPoint;

var d1 = [];
 for (var i = 0; i <= 10; i += 1)
     getcount(i, d1);
...
```

Answer (score 1):

Use jQuery, it will be far easier:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function () {
  var previousPoint, d1 = [];

  var getCount = function(day){
    $.get("getcount.php?"+day, function(data){
      d1.push([day, data]);
    });
  }

  for (var i = 0; i <= 10; i += 1)
    getcount(i)
});
</script>
```

Comment: That doesn't answer his question and just feels like a shameless plug. :[

Answer (score 1):

Mixing any type of Ajax query with a loop of this nature is not a great idea.  It will create some interesting race conditions as the Ajax request is asynchronous - as already mentioned.

It would be better to do a single ajax request and handle the loop in php - then return a single array.  However, again, its important you need to understand by default, the rest of your procedural javascript code will not wait for the Ajax method to return.

See the [docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) for help

Answer (score 0):

```
Try using Jquery ajax which is very easier for maintenance and debugging. Here is a sample 
ajax code

$.ajax({
 type: 'POST',  // can be get also
 url: 'yourpage.php',  // change name
 data: id,  // some data if u need to pass
 success: function(data) {  // returns date
       $('.result').html(data); // result 
 }
}); 

For details  http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Thanks.
```